# Angular2 set language on app starting

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question regarding how to set the language in an Angular2 app. I have a rest service to get language from the backend, so I make an async call but, in the meantime, the application starts without setting the language. My appComponent is:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private service: Service) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getLanguage().subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.result){
          let lang = response.lang.substring(0, response.lang.indexOf('-'));
          this.translate.use(lang);
        } else {
          this.translate.use('en');
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.translate.use('en');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I think this is an incorrect way to set the app language... Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: why have this detail in the component at all use a resolver that will do this job for you when ever the app component is loaded . More on [router resolve](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard)

Answer (score 0):

Way you are doing is right but you can optimize this by using `loader` before getting result from backend like this

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private service: Service) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.loader = true;
        this.service.getLanguage()
            .subscribe(response => {
                    this.loader = false;
                    if (response.result) {
                        let lang = response.lang.substring(0, response.lang.indexOf('-'));
                        this.translate.use(lang);
                    } else {
                        this.translate.use('en');
                    }
                },
                err => {
                    this.loader = false;
                    this.translate.use('en');
                }
            );
    }
}
```

and as per `loader` variable you can show loading image into frontend.